# Remove All data in string after 10th entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data in a string 0871234567ThisPartOfTheStringIsRandom

How Do I update the string to just keep the first 10 Chars?

Please Keep in mind I have thousands of entries where 'ThisPartOfTheStringIsRandom' is different in every case

Answer (score 2):

The [LEFT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-function/) function is a string function that returns the left part of a string with a specified length.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET YourColumn = LEFT(YourColumn,10)
```

Comment: the 'ThisPartOfTheStringIsRandom' could be any length

Comment: However the length, it will take fist 10 characters.